# Django search as input is entered into form

Tags: python, django, search

I currently have a working search form in my project that passes through form data to the GET request. Pretty standard.
What I'm wanting to do is search as data is entered into the search form, so that results will display in real time with search data. This is much like what Google does with the instant desktop results. Is this something that's possible with Django?
Below is my current (simple) search

```
#views.py
def ProductView(request):
title = 'Products'
all_products = Product.objects.all().order_by("product_Name")
query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    products = all_products.filter(
        Q(product_Name__contains=query) |
        Q(manufacturer__contains=query)
    ).distinct()
    return render(request, 'mycollection/details.html', { 'all_products' : products })
```

-

```
<!-- HTML -->
    <!-- SEARCH BAR -->
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'mycollection:products' %}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: By "display in real time" do you mean as the user types (ie. before the GET request is sent?)

Comment: This is of course possible. But, the solution to me sounds much more of a Javascript question. You need to have a working Javascript utility that can make Ajax calls to an endpoint that returns (for example) with a json object of search results that the Javascript then returns to the browser. The problem is that the "how" is a very complex answer that is highly dependent upon your site's front end architecture.

Comment: Yes, denvaar, I am looking to do this without a GET request. The Brewmaster, I am not too keen on Javascript but it is something I need to get more involved with. Would you have an example implementation of what you're referring to that I could try and tailor to my needs?

Answer (score 0):

you can save the request.data in to session and if any data is associated with session search data you can put in to value of search box.

```
request.session['search'] = request.GET.get('q','')
```

templete :

```
{% if request.session.search %} {{request.session.search}} {% endif %}
```